# What alternatives are there for if else statements?

Tags: java

This is a method within my program and I cannot use a bunch of `if-else` statements for my code. I need alternatives.

```
    public String bedRoom1(){

        int newChoice10 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Would "
        + "you like to explore this room?",
        "question",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);


        if (newChoice10 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){  //if the user would lieke to
    // explore then they are given the option for which objects they woul like to explore

            int newChoice4 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Explore"
             + " the Rocking chair(type YES) or Window(type NO)?"
             , "question",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

    //The following if else statments are still within
     //the first statement of the first if statement
            if (newChoice4 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Chair starts "
               + "rocking with no one in it");

            }else{

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You see a child outs"
                  + "ide on a swing and he suddenly vanishes.");
            }
        }else if (newChoice10 == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You have chosen not "
         + "to explore Bedroom 1 and therefore continue "
         + "into the following room");

        }

        return null;



  }
```

Can you please provide examples. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look up switch/case

Comment: Why can't you use if else statements?  They work fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `showOptionDialog` with all your choices instead of `showConfirmDialog`

and use `switch - case` instead of `if then else`